# How to expose an API in python

Tags: python, api, abstraction

I have a directory structure like the following. Assume that `main.py` has to run a few tools that all work slightly differently.

```
topleveldir
├── main.py
├── tool1
│   └── api.py
│   └── many other things...
└── tool2
    └── api.py
    └── many other things...
```

`api.py` contains a set of standard functions that `main.py` can call. I want to design this such that anyone can create a folder called `tool3` and implement the functions inside `api.py` without having to touch anything else and their tool will be integrated into the system.

I'm not sure how to provide a minimal reproducible example, but I'm looking for something like:

main.py:

```
for tool in tools:
    tool.run()
```

tool1/api.py

```
def run():
    print('running tool 1')
```

tool2/api.py

```
def run():
    print('running tool 2')
```

My question is how do I populate the `tools` variable

What is the best way to do this in python?

Comment: Please always provide a [mcve] and be sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-dynamically-load-modules-or-classes-in-python/        
Dynamically loading modules are of help. You can create a list of app#.py in subfolders dynamically and import modules using that list. Then who cares how many app#.py!